# I would like php to "execute" a variable into a string

Tags: php, json, variables, var

I use JSON to organize my PHP code.

I don't know if it's possible but I stocked inside of my Json a PHP variable.
I would like to get it in my PHP script.

I've created my JSON file :

```
{
    "link" : "?id=$org_id"
}
```

In my php, I use the json_decode function.
Then in PHP, I stock the result in a variable

Thus,

```
$org_id = 456;
echo $res; //output "?id=$org_id" while I wanted "?id=456"
```

What can I do?

Comment: I take it back, I see what you're asking, but I'd suggest doing it another way. E.g. using [sprintf](https://www.php.net/sprintf) placeholders in your JSON string, and replacing the placeholder that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo strtr($res, array('$org_id' => $org_id));`

Should substitute the string '$org_id' with the variable $org_id

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly :

If you want to do it entirely in php : contatenate the string with the value that way : `"link" : "?id=".$org_id`

If you're getting the data from your json file and you want to replace it you could use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php).

```
$str = '?id=$org_id';
$replaced = str_replace('$org_id', 456, $str);
echo $replaced;
```

Comment: You don't understand the question, you should delete this answer. The string has already been defined, he's getting out of a json file, he isn't setting it. With the string he already has he wants to substitute the variable $name for the value

Comment: Yes but it's still wrong, the bit with str_replace is correct but the rest shouldn't be there. And you haven't provided the code.